# java.io.IOException: To use Lanterna on Windows, either add JNA (and jna-platform) to the classpath (or use javaw)

Tags: java, windows, jna

### Context

I created a Lanterna TUI which works perfect on Ubuntu, and I am testing it on Windows 11. When I run the command with `javaw`, a separate terminal is created that is glitches as soon as one moves the cursor. Hence I tried to add JNA and jna-platform to the classpath. However the JNA is not being recognised, even though I believe it is in the classpath.

I downloaded the JNA jar files from these 5 links which are listed on [this repository](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna):

- https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/java/dev/jna/jna/5.14.0/jna-5.14.0.jar
- https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/java/dev/jna/jna-jpms/5.14.0/jna-jpms-5.14.0.jar
- https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/java/dev/jna/jna-platform/5.14.0/jna-platform-5.14.0.jar
- https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/java/dev/jna/jna-platform-jpms/5.14.0/jna-platform-jpms-5.14.0.jar
- https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/master/lib/native/win32-x86-64.jar

Yielding files:

- C:\temp\windows_requirements\jna-5.14.0.jar
- C:\temp\windows_requirements\jna-jpms-5.14.0.jar
- C:\temp\windows_requirements\jna-platform-5.14.0.jar
- C:\temp\windows_requirements\jna-platform-jpms-5.14.0.jar
- C:\temp\windows_requirements\win32-x86-64.jar

### Approach I

I tried including jna in the dependencies of the `gradle.build` file using:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    // Use Lanterna on Windows
    implementation 'net.java.dev.jna:jna:5.14.0'
    ...
}
```

Even though it compiles and runs perfectly fine (on Ubuntu), it still throws the same error as below on Windows.

### Approach II

Then tried to include the jna and jna platform using:

```bash
java -classpath "C:temp\windows_requirements\jna-5.14.0.jar;C:\temp\windows_requirements\jna-platform-5.14.0.jar;C:\temp\some-project-all.jar" -jar some-project-all.jar
```

However, that outputs the same error as below.

### Approach III

I changed the classpath, by first asserting the jna and jna-platform `.jar` files exist on the system, and then adding them to the classpath using:

```java
String classpath = System.getProperty("java.class.path");
    System.out.println("Classpath="+classpath+"END");
    File jnaJarFile = new File("C:/temp/windows_requirements/jna-5.14.0.jar");
    File jnaPlatformJarFile = new File("C:/temp/windows_requirements/jna-platform-5.14.0.jar");

    if (!jnaJarFile.exists() || !jnaJarFile.isFile()) {
      throw new FileNotFoundException("jnaJarFile:"+jnaJarFile.getAbsolutePath()+" does not exist.");
    }
    if (!jnaPlatformJarFile.exists() || !jnaPlatformJarFile.isFile()) {
      throw new FileNotFoundException("jnaPlatformJarFile:"+jnaPlatformJarFile.getAbsolutePath()+" does not exist.");
    }
      
    // Append the directory or JAR file to the classpath
    classpath += ";"+jnaJarFile+";"+jnaPlatformJarFile; // Use ; as separator in Windows
    // Set the updated classpath
    System.setProperty("java.class.path", classpath);
    // Print the updated classpath
    System.out.println("Updated Classpath: " + System.getProperty("java.class.path"));
```

Furthermore, I ensured the jna dependency is in the `build.gradle` file, which is then used to create a `.jar` that contains all dependencies using: `clear && ./gradlew build shadowJar`:

```
implementation 'net.java.dev.jna:jna:5.14.0'
```

This `.jar` that contains all the dependencies is than used to run the code above with: `java -jar build/libs/some-project-all.jar`.

However, that still outputs:

```
Classpath=some-project-all.jarEND
Updated Classpath: some-project-all.jar;C:\temp\windows_requirements\jna-5.14.0.jar;C:\temp\windows_requirements\jna-platform-5.14.0.jar
....
java.IOException: To use Lanterna on Windows, either add JNA (and jna-platform) to the classpath or use javaw! (see https://github.com/mabe02/lanterna/issues/335)
```

### Question

How can I ensure the `some-project-all.jar` file recognises the JNA (and jna-platform) on windows?

### Java Version

The java version that I am using on Ubuntu is found by:

```
java --version
openjdk 19.0.2 2023-01-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 19.0.2+7-44)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.0.2+7-44, mixed mode, sharing)
```

And on Windows:

```
java 21.0.1 2023-10-17 LTS
JRE: 21.0.1+12-LTS-29
```

Comment: Some [System] properties **cannot** be changed after the JVM is created, including _java.class.path_. You must ensure that the JNA jars are part of the CLASSPATH when you execute the `java` (or `javaw`) command. I don't use gradle so I can't help you with that. I also don't know what you mean by a "fat jar". In order to simply create an application JAR, you need to create a custom [manifest](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/specs/jar/jar.html) and add relevant `Class-Path` attributes. By the way, what Java version are you using?

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I included the description for adding the classpath at the CLI, and replaced "fat jar" with "jar that contains all the dependencies". Furthermore, I will look into how to add the class path attributes.

Comment: It will be worth your time to figure out how to fetch all your dependencies from Maven Central using either Maven or Gradle.  Manually dealing with class paths is a recipe for pain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was found in the comment by Daniel Widdis. The issue was that I did not include the `jna-platform` in the `build.gradle` file. I had already included the `jna` dependency in the `build.gradle` however, I did not include the `jna-platform` dependency as well. After including both with:

```yaml
dependencies {
    // Use Lanterna on Windows
    implementation 'net.java.dev.jna:jna:5.14.0'
    implementation 'net.java.dev.jna:jna-platform:5.14.0'
}
```

and compiled the jar, it showed the Lanterna TUI on Windows, without the glitches shown with `javaw`. Verified on Windows 11 on a virtual machine on Ubuntu 23.04.